# How to put page numbers with the next/previous on a post/category list?

Tags: categories, posts, feed, pages

Is there a way to add numbering to the latest posts/category listing pages? By default you can put older/newer, but is there a way to add numbering like page 1,2,3,4 of the list so people can skip ahead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [wp-pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/)
its a plugin which adds advanced paging navigation to your WordPress site just like you asked.

Comment: Awesome. I was searching and searching for a plugin but I guess I didn't use the right terms. Now I just need to see how much I can customize it.